# Write to new non-existent file in same directory, Python 2.7

Tags: python, file, directory, new-operator

I'm trying to read a document and write it into a new file (that doesn't exist) in the same directory as the read file

An example would be

```
test_infile='/Users/name/Desktop/test.txt'

in_file=open(test_infile,'r')
data=in_file.readlines()
out_file=open('test_outfile.csv','w')
```

out_file should create a new file called test_outfile.csv in the directory /Users/name/Desktop/test_outfile.csv

---

I worked with the os module and got

```
def function(test):
    import os
    in_file=open(test,'r')
    dir,file=os.path.split(test)
    temp=os.path.join('output.csv')
    out_file=open('output.csv','w')

 test_file='/Users/name/Desktop/test.txt'
 function(test_file)
```

it runs but nothing is created ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `os.path.split` function to split the directory path from the file name, and then the `os.path.join` function to stitch path constituents together:

```
import os
dir, file = os.path.split(test_infile)
out_file_name = os.path.join(dir, 'test_outfile.csv')
```

Please make sure you read the documentation of these functions, and the `os.path` module in general, since it's very useful.

Comment: os.path.dirname(test_infile) is nicer if you don't need the file name

Comment: @jterrace: good comment. I usually use `os.path.split` since most of the times you do need the file too, but here `dirname` could also work

Comment: hm . . it doesn't seem to work in my function . i got it to work outside of the function

Comment: def function(test):
    import os
    in_file=open(test,'r')
    dir,file=os.path.split(test)
    temp=os.path.join('output.csv')
    out_file=open('output.csv','w')

    test_file='/Users/name/Desktop/test.txt'


it runs but nothing is created ?

Comment: @draconisthe0ry: *that* may be a separate problem

Comment: nvm got it
i forgot the dir in temp=os.path.join(dir,'output.csv')